# How to set UIfields using masonry in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

Hi i am beginner for `Auto-Layouts` and i am inserting some fields on my `UIScrollView` they are `UILabels` and `UIButtons` and `UITextfields` using `Masonry` but i am very ignore about `Masonry` concept please help me.

I want screen exactly like below image using `Masonry` concept and i have started some code for doing this requirement but middle of moments i was strucked to do this requirement please help me how to full fill my requirement

### my code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Masonry.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UITextField * textfield1 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textfield1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    textfield1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:textfield1];

        UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

        [scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top);
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
    }];

    UIEdgeInsets padding1 = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 100, 10, 0);

    [textfield1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make1){

        make1.top.equalTo(scrollView.mas_top).width.offset(padding1.top);
        make1.left.equalTo(scrollView.mas_left).with.offset(padding1.left);
        make1.height.equalTo(scrollView.mas_height).with.offset(30);
        make1.right.equalTo(scrollView.mas_right).with.offset(-padding1.right);

    }];

}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to make it work. I did not do all labels but enough to give you an idea how this should be implemented:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField1;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField2;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *textField3;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *leftButton;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *rightButton;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    self.label1.text = @"Label 1";
    self.leftButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.leftButton setTitle:@"Left Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.rightButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.rightButton setTitle:@"Right Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.textField1.placeholder = @"TextField 1";
    self.textField2.placeholder = @"TextField 2";
    self.textField3.placeholder = @"TextField 3";
    self.textField1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1];
    self.textField2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1];
    self.textField3.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1];


    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.label1];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.textField1];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.textField2];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.textField3];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.leftButton];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.rightButton];

    [self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 10, 10, 10));
    }];

    [self.label1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.left.right.equalTo(@0);
        make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView);
    }];

    [self.textField1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.label1.mas_bottom);
        make.left.right.equalTo(@0);
        make.height.equalTo(@30);
    }];

    [self.textField2 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.textField1.mas_bottom).offset(20);
        make.left.equalTo(@0);
        make.height.equalTo(self.textField1);
    }];

    [self.textField3 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.textField2);
        make.left.equalTo(self.textField2.mas_right).offset(20);
        make.right.equalTo(@0);
        make.width.equalTo(self.textField2).multipliedBy(0.7);
        make.height.equalTo(self.textField1);
    }];

    [self.leftButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.textField2.mas_bottom).offset(40);
        make.left.equalTo(@0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(@0);
    }];
    [self.rightButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.leftButton);
        make.right.equalTo(@0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(@0);
        make.width.equalTo(self.leftButton);
    }];
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

If you want to know a bit more about UIScrollViews and AutoLayout, here is a short blog post I wrote about this topic: [UIScrollView and Auto Layout](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/uiscrollview-and-auto-layout/)